# what is the right way to write this helper code in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, lightbox

i use light box but something wrong with this code to show light-box
 instead of

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

i use this code for view

```
   $thumb = $this->Html->image('images/thumb-1.jpg');
    $full = $this->Html->image('/images/image-1.jpg', array('rel' => 'lightbox'));
    echo $this->Html->link($thumb,$full, array('escape' => false));
```

but i see this error

```
Error: The action <img src=" is not defined in controller ImagesController

Error: Create ImagesController::<img src="() in file: app\controllers\images_controller.php.

<?php
class ImagesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Images';


    function <img src="() {

    }

}
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\views\errors\missing_action.ctp
```

Comment: What the problem you're encountering in implementing this?

Comment: the problem is how to display images in lightbox gallery like this http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Can you display the images *without* Lightbox?

Comment: yes i can but i want to display it in box gallery

Comment: So the database part of the question is irrelevant? What have you tried regarding the Lightbox, what didn't work?

Comment: this database code just example from my database,my problem that i didnt have any idea to display images with jquery lightbox or any jquery popup box..i hope that u understand me.. please see this link to know what i mean http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Have you tried following [the instructions](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#how)? If so, what didn't work? Your question is really "how do I set up Lightbox2", but you have only given irrelevant details about your database, not about the problems you have in setting up Lightbox2.

Comment: i chaneged my question...sorry..but this instructions for static code..i need some instructions for cakephp..thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried looking at the generated HTML?

Comment: hi deceze please help me this is the  generated code <a href="http://localhost/tet/img/images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="17_files/thumb-1.jpg" alt="" height="40" width="200"></a>

Comment: the code is correct the two picture appear but the jquery effect not appear

Answer (score 1):

Translating [the instructions](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#how):

> Lightbox 2 uses the Prototype Framework and Scriptaculous Effects Library. You will need to include these three Javascript files in your
>   header (in this order).
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
> ```

For Cake that means to put these lines into your `default.ctp` layout and the Javascript files into the `webroot/js` folder.

> Include the Lightbox CSS file (or append your active stylesheet with the Lightbox styles).
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
> ```

Again, put this in the layout and the css file into `webroot/css`.

> Check the CSS and make sure the referenced `prev.gif` and `next.gif`
>   files are in the right location. Also, make sure the `loading.gif` and
>   `close.gif` files as referenced near the top of the `lightbox.js` file
>   are in the right location.

Make sure the images are in the right location in `webroot/img`, adjust paths as necessary.

> Add a rel="lightbox" attribute to any link tag to activate the
>   lightbox. For example:
>
> ```
> <a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
> ```

In you do this by adding attributes to the link helper:

```
$this->Html->link('image #1', '/img/images-1.jpg', array('rel' => 'lightbox'));
```

Comment: i follow all steps but something wrong with this code $thumb = $this->Html->image('images/thumb-1.jpg');
$full = $this->Html->image('/images/image-1.jpg', array('rel' => 'lightbox'));
echo $this->Html->link($thumb,$full, array('escape' => false));

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not listed any code you tried, so i assume you've not started integration. Check this link, it have what you need:
[Lightbox using CakePHP](http://cocoacrusty.com/?p=106)

Comment: thanks sidhir..but i saw all comments under this article say it is not work with them

Comment: edited , see the link, may be that will help you get started. Hope it helps